# AWS Fargate - CannotPullContainerError (500)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm using AWS ECS to host my services. When I try to define task with fargate, I'm getting this below problem.

> CannotPullContainerError: API error (500): Get https://xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Further I gave full permissions to access ECR  in the IAM user as well. Please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [STOPPED (CannotPullContainerError: API error (500): Get htt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368499/stopped-cannotpullcontainererror-api-error-500-get-htt)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look here: https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/1128

In particular, the comment by [samuelkarp](https://github.com/samuelkarp)

> The error you are seeing below is commonly due to lack of internet
>   access to pull the image. The image pull occurs over the network
>   interface used by the Task, and as such shares security group and
>   routing rules.
>
> Please check your configuration for the following:
>
> If you are launching a task without a public IP, make sure that the
>   route table on the subnet has "0.0.0.0/0" going to a NAT Gateway or
>   NAT instance to ensure access to the internet. If your route table has
>   an internet gateway, this is acting like a firewall and preventing the
>   connection from being made. If you are launching a task with a public
>   IP, make sure that the route table on the subnet has "0.0.0.0/0" going
>   to an internet gateway to ensure you will be able to use the public IP
>   successfully for ingress traffic. Verify your security group rules for
>   the Task allows for outbound access. The default here is typically All
>   Traffic to 0.0.0.0/0. If neither of those networking changes apply to
>   you or if they do not fix your problem, please let us know so we can
>   further assist.

Comment: I'd like to add: Also be careful to not accidentally put your container into a private subnet without internet access.

Comment: Why does AWS suck so much at making it simple to use their services?

Comment: I'm seeing this abruptly; it has worked historically and I don't think anything has changed in our infrastructure...

Comment: @kev much because it's not meant to be just "easy to use". There are always tradeoffs that comes with simplicity, resulting in limited flexibility. AWS is basically renting you infrastructure, while it's management is your responsibility. They are rolling simpler to use services though, like Fargate launch type with ECS (but at a greater price than managing your own EC2 infra).

Comment: I am also seeing this error on occasion with services that normally work. I have auto public ip and a NAT gateway attached to fargate. When the error does come up, it likes to persist for a while.

Answer (score 13):

I've already answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59211558/3633671), but copy-paste does not hurt.

The specification for creating a working NAT Gateway is lacking. At the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/1128) Amazon technicians keep repeating you "just" need Private IP + NAT, however this is not true. I struggled with this myself **a lot**, but finally got it working properly without using a Public IP for my Fargate services.

To have Fargate services access internet without having a Public IP you need to set up a VPC which has 2 subnets:

- A **public** subnet with an Internet Gateway allowing **bidirectional** internet access
- A **private** subnet with a NAT Gateway allowing **only outgoing** internet access

You can create such a VPC in 2 ways: by going to `Services` > `VPC` > `VPC Dashboard`, clicking on `Launch VPC Wizard` and selecting `"VPC with Public and Private Subnets"`; or manually:

*NOTE: All of the following steps are performed in `Services` > `VPC`*

1. Go to `Your VPCs` and `Create a VPC`
2. Go to `Subnets` and `Create subnet` 2 times

   1. **`private`** subnet

      1. Attach it to the VPC in focus. Whatever CIDR block, whatever availability zone you like
   2. **`public`** subnet

      1. Attach it to the VPC in focus. Whatever CIDR block, whatever availability zone you like
3. Go to `Internet Gateways` and `Create internet gateway`

   1. Name it however you want
   2. Select the newly created `Internet Gateway`, `Actions`, `Attach to VPC` and attach it to the VPC in focus
4. Go to `NAT Gateways` and `Create NAT Gateway`

   1. **Important:** Select the **`public`** subnet
   2. `Create New EIP` or use an existing one given that you have one
   3. Wait for the gateway to become `Available`
5. Go to `Route Tables` and `Create route table` 2 times

   1. **`private`** route table

      1. Attach it to the VPC in focus
      2. Back at the list, **select** the route table
      3. `Routes` tab on the bottom, `Edit routes`
      4. `Add route`, destination: `0.0.0.0/0`, target the NAT Gateway created previously and `Save routes`
      5. Still having the route table **selected**, `Actions` and `Set Main Route Table` (if not already)
   2. **`public`** route table

      1. Attach it to the VPC in focus
      2. Back at the list, **select** the route table
      3. `Routes` tab on the bottom, `Edit routes`
      4. `Add route`, destination: `0.0.0.0/0`, target the Internet Gateway created previously and `Save routes`
      5. `Subnet Associations` tab on the bottom, `Edit subnet associations`
      6. Select the **`public`** subnet, `Save`
6. Put cucumber on eyes.

Every service you put in the **`public`** subnet will have **bidirectional** internet access and every service you put in the **`private`** subnet will have **only outgoing** internet access (yes, Fargate and EC2 services in the **`private`** subnet without Public IPs will have internet access).

Comment: Is Setting main route table necessary?

Comment: @AbhyuditJain if you are following the manual steps, then yes.