# STOPPED (CannotPullContainerError: API error (500)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm getting this error when running a task on my Amazon Fargate cluster. Has anyone seen run into this before?

Comment: looks like you've mistyped `http` as `htt` in your repo, most likely

Comment: https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/1128 possibly this one can help

Comment: I'm also working through this...it's not a typo @MrDuk it's just that they truncate the log in the ECS console

Comment: Austin, have you found a resoultion for this? I'm trying to solve the same thing -- all SGs are correct, routing to a NAT instance is correct, etc etc

Comment: Related: [AWS Fargate - CannotPullContainerError (500)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48226547/55075)

Answer (score 6):

Go to the docs for an answer to this one.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_cannot_pull_image.html

Since you are encountering a `500` error, I would heed the advice of the first error's description, "Connection timed out":

> When a Fargate task is launched, its elastic network interface requires a route to the internet to pull container images. If you receive an error similar to the following when launching a task, it is because a route to the internet does not exist:
>
> ```
> CannotPullContainerError: API error (500): Get https://111122223333.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection
> ```
>
> To resolve this issue, you can:
>
> - For tasks in public subnets, specify **ENABLED** for **Auto-assign public IP** when launching the task...
> - For tasks in private subnets, specify **DISABLED** for **Auto-assign public IP** when launching the task, and configure a NAT Gateway in your VPC to route requests to the internet...

If you encountering any other issues relating to ECS Tasks not starting or exhibiting weird behavior upon starting, then check the full list of [ECS troubleshooting topics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/troubleshooting.html).

I was encountering a similar error (`404` instead of `500`), however, the Task displayed that it was RUNNING even though the detailed status listed an error.

It turns out that the role associated with the task (same role as the EC2 Instance on which it was running, in this case) could not be assumed by ecs-tasks. Adding the following trust relationship statement to the role resolved the issue:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
  },
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
}
```

See the specific page on the [Task Execution Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

Assigning a *Public IP* is mandatory for Fargate.
For details see https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/1128

Comment: I believe the Fargate launch type does not require assignment of Public IPs. Under "Task Networking Considerations" of [this Doc page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html) it says, "You can configure [Fargate launch type] tasks to receive public IP addresses", implying that it is optional. This would make sense if you want to deploy a task in a private subnet of a vpc (using the 'awsvpc' network mode).

Answer (score 5):

Public IP is **not mandatory**, the specification for creating a working NAT Gateway is lacking. At the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/1128) Amazon technicians keep repeating you "just" need Private IP + NAT, however this is not true. I struggled with this myself **a lot**, but finally got it working properly without using a Public IP for my Fargate services.

To have Fargate services access internet without having a Public IP you need to set up a VPC which has 2 subnets:

- A **public** subnet with an Internet Gateway allowing **bidirectional** internet access
- A **private** subnet with a NAT Gateway allowing **only outgoing** internet access

You can create such a VPC in 2 ways: by going to `Services` > `VPC` > `VPC Dashboard`, clicking on `Launch VPC Wizard` and selecting `"VPC with Public and Private Subnets"`; or manually:

*NOTE: All of the following steps are performed in `Services` > `VPC`*

1. Go to `Your VPCs` and `Create a VPC`
2. Go to `Subnets` and `Create subnet` 2 times

   1. **`private`** subnet

      1. Attach it to the VPC in focus. Whatever CIDR block, whatever availability zone you like
   2. **`public`** subnet

      1. Attach it to the VPC in focus. Whatever CIDR block, whatever availability zone you like
3. Go to `Internet Gateways` and `Create internet gateway`

   1. Name it however you want
   2. Select the newly created `Internet Gateway`, `Actions`, `Attach to VPC` and attach it to the VPC in focus
4. Go to `NAT Gateways` and `Create NAT Gateway`

   1. **Important:** Select the **`public`** subnet
   2. `Create New EIP` or use an existing one given that you have one
   3. Wait for the gateway to become `Available`
5. Go to `Route Tables` and `Create route table` 2 times

   1. **`private`** route table

      1. Attach it to the VPC in focus
      2. Back at the list, **select** the route table
      3. `Routes` tab on the bottom, `Edit routes`
      4. `Add route`, destination: `0.0.0.0/0`, target the NAT Gateway created previously and `Save routes`
      5. Still having the route table **selected**, `Actions` and `Set Main Route Table` (if not already)
   2. **`public`** route table

      1. Attach it to the VPC in focus
      2. Back at the list, **select** the route table
      3. `Routes` tab on the bottom, `Edit routes`
      4. `Add route`, destination: `0.0.0.0/0`, target the Internet Gateway created previously and `Save routes`
      5. `Subnet Associations` tab on the bottom, `Edit subnet associations`
      6. Select the **`public`** subnet, `Save`
6. Put cucumber on eyes.

Every service you put in the **`public`** subnet will have **bidirectional** internet access and every service you put in the **`private`** subnet will have **only outgoing** internet access (yes, Fargate and EC2 services in the **`private`** subnet without Public IPs will have internet access).

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when the container is unable to pull the container from the registry.

1. Check that you're allocating a public IP address to your containers. Currently the AWS container registry doesn't have an internal-in-vpn endpoint.
2. Check that your containers have a way to connect to the internet (eg: nat instance or similar.
3. Check that the security group that you have associated with the container allows outbound traffic. If you created the SG with terraform or similar you may find that it's defaulting to having no outbound rules.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate a Public Ip to your service, you can do it during the Service definition but as far as I know you can not update your service from the update menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running ECS in a private VPC without Internet access, set up a [VPC endpoint for ECR and S3 first](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your subnet has access to the internet. In my case, the fargate task was deployed to a private subnet. While this subnet had the nat gateway configured, the public subnet, did not have a route to the internet gateway.